# Batch convert geojson "circle" to polygon objects, then define 2dsphere index from collection of polygons

Tags: python, ruby, mongodb, geojson

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so go easy!

High level goal is this: find the intersection of apartments on craigslist with locations that are under 35m from my work.

I've used kimono labs' API builder to extract the addresses of apartments within my price range on Craigslist, and then converted those addresses to longitude/latitude coordinates.

I also have a list of pseudo-geoJson objects collectively describing the area within 35m, generated from mapnificent.net; eg

```
{"type":"Feature",
    "properties":{"radius":1153.8461538461538},
    "geometry":{"type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[-73.97367450000002,
        40.7589832]
    }
},
```

First question is: how can I batch-convert these, in mongoDB or elsewhere, to a list of regular geoJSON polygons approximating the area that Mongo can understand?

Second question is: once I have a collection of regular polygons, how can I use all ~4,000 of these objects to define a 2dsphere index I can use to intersect with my list of points from Craigslist?

I have basic familiarity with MongoDB, Python, Ruby, and Java, but am by no means an expert. Quick learner though -- a day ago I didn't even know what geoJSON was or how to run MongoDB.

Thanks!